# What is the meaning of judge's statement?

Tags: meaning

[SOURCE](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107207/synopsis)

> The judge makes a point of stating that he'd give Gerry the death
>   penalty for treason if Gerry had been so accused.

What is the meaning of judge's statement?

Comment: The writing at your link is a little off-the-cuff; this should be "...stating that he *would have given* ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gerry and the others were accused of various crimes that **did not** include treason. They were found guilty and given lengthy sentences. In other words, they will be in prison for a long time, if not their entire lives. So the judge's statement implies that something like

> You're lucky you weren't accused with treason, or else I would have sentenced you to death!

Or at the very least, he is implying that Gerry deserves to be sentenced to death for his crimes.